# clear textarea element

Tags: jquery, textarea, element

I'm curios if it's possible to clear textarea element when a div element is clicked.

I've started with this markup:

```
jQuery('.hoverbgpfthnailiface').click(function(e){
    var target = e.target;

    while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
    if(target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA'){
        jQuery('.header-search-form').css({ 'display' : 'none' });
        jQuery('*').show();
    }

});​
```

My question is how can I clear also the textarea element when that specific div is clicked? 
Thanks!

Comment: What's the id of your textarea that you want to clear?

Comment: By clear, do you mean hide or to remove the text ?

Comment: @adeneo I believe he means to just clear the text inside of it or set the value to empty string

Comment: I want to remove the text after the div is clicked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the value to `''`

```
$('#id_of_your_textarea').val('');
```

Comment: Thanks! But actually in my scenario it doesnt work. I have a live search content so actually I need to mimic the  "backspace" button to clear the search input. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTdwU/9/)

Comment: @Alecs This Fiddle is very far from your original question. But my answer still applies. Give an `id` to your `<input>`, because the `class` is removed by the search method. Then as I said, do a `val('')`. All you need to do then is reset your content. Since the search hides the non matching elements, a simple `$('*').show();` will do.

Comment: I've put $('*').show(); in my code but it's strange that is not working, I've updated my post to see how I've add the code.

Comment: Now it seems to work, it was the cache. I have another small question: I want to use $('*').show(); when a specific div is clicked